# how to test parameters using properties file in junit

Tags: java, junit

I was preparing a test case scenario where I put the values to be tested against their keys in `properties` file. I wanted if all key values satisfied with their corresponding values, the method should return true, else false.

Below is my code:

```
package mypackTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Test123 {

    static Properties p = null;
    private boolean expected;

    @Parameters
    public static List<String[]> data() 
    {
      String[][] data = new String[][] { { "D:\\personal\\config.properties" }};
   return Arrays.asList(data);
    }


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup()
    {  
          p = new Properties();
        try 
        {
           //load a properties file 
            p.load(new FileReader(new File("D:\\personal\\config.properties")));
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
       ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}



    @Test
    public void do_test() {

        assertThat(TestThis.letstest(p.getProperty("abc1"), p.getProperty("abc2")), is(expected));
    }
}
```

***the class that I wanted to test upon:***

```
package mypackTest;

public class TestThis {

    public static boolean letstest(String abc1,String abc2){
        if(abc1.equals("xyz1")&& abc2.equals("xyz2")){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

***properties file***

```
abc1=xyz1
abc2=xyz2
```

***TestRunner class***

```
package mypackTest;

import java.util.Enumeration;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

import junit.framework.TestFailure;
import junit.framework.TestResult;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

              Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(CalculatorTest.class);

              for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
                 System.out.println(failure.toString());
              }

              System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

I am getting below output

***OUTPUT***

do_test0: wrong number of arguments

false

Answer (score 1):

There are various problems with this code. First of all:

```
private boolean expected;
```

You are declaring that field - but you **never** assign a value to it. Thus it is initialized to `false` and stays `false`. So don't expect that it comparing it to something that is `true` would work out.

But beyond that: the way you are using `Parametrized` doesn't make **any** sense. The idea of this special runner is: the @Parameters "thing" contains **multiple** values; and your test is invoked in a loop for each entry. Having a **single** file name there - that is like "buying for a truck to then transport a single suitcase". Meaning: you would rather specify a list of key/value entries there; and then (for example) make sure that a property file contains all these entries. Or something like that.

So the real answer is: step back and learn about the basics. For example your usage of **static** is also implying that you have no understanding of what *static* actually is, and when to use it. And then **follow** a tutorial for JUnit (normal JUnit). And when you figured how to use that properly, then read a tutorial about @Parametrized.

In other words: don't apply "trial and error" when you are lacking basic understanding. This strategy *only* works when you have enough experience to not always *error* immediately for anything you try.